# How to copy files after build when using AWS for Visual Studio to deploy to Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

I need to copy files after build to be included in the bin directory of a project I'm deploying to Elastic Beanstalk via Visual Studio.

When using the built-in VS publish tool, I use:

```
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
<ItemGroup>
  <_CustomFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\Lib\Neurotec\native\x64\*" />
  <_CustomFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)\Lib\Neurotec\Faces.ndf" />
  <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
    <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
  </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
</ItemGroup>
</Target>
<PropertyGroup>
   <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>CustomCollectFiles;
  ;</CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
<CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>CustomCollectFiles;
  ;</CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

How can I use a similar build step when using the AWS tools for Visual Studio to deploy?

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this question?

Comment: i did not. but the sdk i'm using also looks for the native dlls in the system path, which eliminated the need for deploying these files in the first place. hope this puts you on the right track.